# Organizer said I would be reimbursed if I didn't attend, but then changed their mind

Tags: contract-law, small-claims-court

This question is out of curiosity. I was going on a trip with a very informal group of people. I had given the organizer money (for transportation, housing, food etc.) but then had something come up. I asked prior to the trip if I could get my money back. They said yes. After the trip when I asked for my money back they said they might not be able to give it to me as there wasn't much money left over after paying for gas.

Is this legal?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably legal.

If this is arrangement between friends/acquaintances then the presumption is that it is **not** a contract.

From a legal perspective, you gave them money as a gift. They don't have to give it back.

Comment: In the United States I believe this could constitute a verbal contract.

Comment: @Viktor you would have to overcome the presumption that social agreements lack the requisite intention for the parties to be legally bound.

Comment: I should have specified, it may be informal but it's more than a group of friends. It is a club I signed a waver for but there was no paper work for the particular trip (aside from my name being written on a list).